# Why I still see the same js version in my server even when I've changed it?

Tags: javascript, ftp

I'm updating a js file and the browser serves the same old file.

I've uploaded the file through FTP. I see the correct file there (when I open from the FTP program is the correct version).

But the browser shows the old file. I've clicked on the page source and the file is there with the older version.

So I've tried again, this time deleting the file first. I'm not using any cache system or CDN at the moment.

Then **I tried changing the browser**: I was using Firefox, closed it and then accessed the file using Chrome, thinking that I could be the browser that was caching it...

**Still it shows the old version.**

**This is the file:**
https://ligadelconsorcista.online/js/formularios.js

And this is the chunk of code that I'm changing:

```
  $("form[name='cargarDoc']").validate({
    errorClass:'alert alert-danger',
    rules: {
              dni: {
                required: true,
                extension: "gif|jpeg|jpg|png"
              },
              estudios: {
                required: true,
                extension: "gif|jpeg|jpg|png"
              },
              foto: {
                required: true,
                extension: "gif|jpeg|jpg|png"
              }              
            },
    messages:{
              dni: {
                required: "Debes enviar copia del DNI",
                extension: "Solamente puedes cargar archivos del tipo: gif, jpeg, jpg o png"
              },
              estudios: {
                required: "Debes enviar copia del certificado de estudios",
                extension: "Solamente puedes cargar archivos del tipo: gif, jpeg, jpg o png"
              },
              foto: {
                required: "Debes enviar una foto tuya actualizada",
                extension: "Solamente puedes cargar archivos del tipo: gif, jpeg, jpg o png"
              }                            
    }
  });
```

I've took away the required fields (ie. `required: false`). But I still see the `required: true,` version!

Comment: Clear your browser cache.

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com/ » Your browser still has the old version cached.

Comment: Open the file path in your browser and force refresh it. Or open web inspector and select "disable cache".

Comment: To avoid those problem. Change your JS file name with a newer version. eg: `myJS-v1.0` then `myJS-v1.1`

Comment: try to access files in incognito mode or private surfing with safari.

Comment: But how can that be when I've changed the browser? I've even tried incognito mode...

Comment: @Weedoze change the file name is 100% wrong, just add a version number to the end of the link ex: `?v=1` will bust the cache.

Comment: Well if it's not the cache, then the only other possibility is that your FTP uploads are not working as you think they are; you could be uploading to the wrong path, for example.

Comment: @DanielH Why is it 100% wrong ?

Comment: @Weedoze cus you don't need to do that.

Comment: @DanielH *You don't need* doesn't mean that it is 100% wrong. Please explain me the reason. I can't understand why

Comment: @Weedoze: Changing file names (and the script tag with it) is a hassle. A query parameter is extremely easy to update.

Comment: When I disable the cache from the web inspector open, it does work. But only then, I still can't get why.

Comment: @Rosamunda: Chrome has some pretty aggressive caching.

Comment: @Cerbrus I am doing this with a gulp task. Everything works fine and is automated. I cannot understand why it is better to add version apart from the hassle

Comment: @Weedoze Changing file name requires the developer to change all the instances where that file is used as an external js. Assume that js file is used at multiple locations. Then each time you change the file name you have to change all the imports. But the query parameter can be easily used in a configurable manner.

Comment: @DonD That's a point. In my case, I have only one concatenated/minify JS file with a random name.

Comment: Thank you, it was all about the caching, I was mislead by the fact that I've used two different browsers and even incognito mode. The thing that showed me that the new file was really in place was disabling the cache from the development tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try ***ctrl+shif+delete*** and clear browser cache. or try ***ctrl+f5*** (hard refresh)

Comment: How about, instead of answering ever single "clear your cache" question, we just close them, instead?

Comment: it shows that u don't have a mindset to help people. may be it is a simple problem/answer. it solves their big issues.

Comment: I didn't get 41k rep by not helping people. However, duplicating content on extremely simple questions isn't helping _anyone_.

Comment: atleast let him see the answer that would help. then delete the post or do whatever. no problem. and i dint notice your reputation. now i got to know. sorry.

Comment: Usually, we close these questions as duplicate, which means the OP will see a link to a relevant (answered) question.

Comment: yeah. i understood the concept. my intention was only to answer. but someone downvoted for proper answer also.. feeling bad.